# Hibernate: How to fetch or load a lazy entity from another entity on base of particular condition?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I want to load "getBulla" in the following example but on the base of comparison with "getControl".

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bullabase", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<BullaBase> getbulla() {
   return this.bulla;
}

@Column(name = "Control", length = 40)
public String getControl() {
   return Control; //values: Mahidana, Gana, Funa, Khana, Bona, Nona, Raka, Tuka etc.
}
```

`getControl` contains 10 - 15 different static strings but bulla should be load on base of particular condition i.e Load all Entity and get Bulla entity only for `control == "mahidana"` and that too in single fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont think there is an out of the box solution but a workaround would be a wrap around method which would internally initialize the collection upon certain condition:

```
public class CustomEntityRepo{



    public Entity findById(Long id){

        Entity entity = session.get(Entity.class, id);

        if(entity.getControl.equals(\* custom condition*\)){
            entity.getBulla.().size(); // init the collection
        }

        return entity;
    }

}
```